# Extend jquery.css function to override !important styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a mail template editor, users can import their existing templates and redesign the template using our visual editor. If the element the user change has **!important** style property; we have to override the property with **jquery.css**.

**Ex:**

```
 <div id="sendwrapper">
      <button> Send </button>
 </div>
```

**Style**

```
#sendwrapper * {
   color:white !important;
}
```

I want to change the color **white** to **green**. I tried this plugin https://github.com/premasagar/important/blob/master/important.js. This plugin is not so intelligent it set **!important** for all properties but I expect it should set **!important** only for the properties which set **!important**.

Comment: `body #sendwrapper * {color:blue !important}`

Comment: `#sendwrapper#sendwrapper * {color: green !important;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser supports [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (ES6), you can use this plugin:

```js
if ( // Check browser support
  window.Proxy
  && window.CSSStyleDeclaration
  && CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.setProperty
) {
  jQuery.cssHooks = new Proxy(jQuery.cssHooks, {
    get: function(hooks, name) {
      return new Proxy(hooks[name] || (hooks[name] = {}), {
        has: function (hook, setget) {
          return setget === 'set' || setget in hook;
        },
        get: function (hook, setget){
          if(setget !== 'set') return hook[setget];
          return function(elem, value, extra) {

            // Use the cssHook setter, if any
            if(hook.set) {
              value = hook.set(elem, value, extra);
              if(value === void 0) return; // No value
            }

            // Set the desired value without !important
            elem.style[ name ] = value;

            // Get the computed value
            var computedValue = jQuery.css(elem, name);

            // Check if the computed value is the desired one
            if(computedValue === value) return; // OK

            // Set the desired value with !important
            elem.style.setProperty(name, value, "important");

            // Check if the computed value has changed
            if(computedValue !== jQuery.css(elem, name)) return; // OK

            // Otherwise !important is not needed, so remove it
            elem.style.setProperty(name, value);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```js
// Plugin compiled with Closure Compiler
window.Proxy&&window.CSSStyleDeclaration&&CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.setProperty&&(jQuery.cssHooks=new Proxy(jQuery.cssHooks,{get:function(f,b){return new Proxy(f[b]||(f[b]={}),{has:function(b,a){return"set"===a||a in b},get:function(e,a){return"set"!==a?e[a]:function(d,c,a){if(e.set&&(c=e.set(d,c,a),void 0===c))return;d.style[b]=c;a=jQuery.css(d,b);a!==c&&(d.style.setProperty(b,c,"important"),a===jQuery.css(d,b)&&d.style.setProperty(b,c))}}})}}));

// The elements in the collection that need !important will use it
$('.color').css('color', 'blue');

// The plugin is compatible with custom cssHooks
$.cssHooks.opacity.set = function(elem, value) { return value/4 + '' };
$('.opacity').css('opacity', .8);
```

```css
.color {
   color: red;
}
.color.important {
   color: red !important;
}
.opacity.important {
   opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="color">color: blue</div>
<div class="color important">color: blue !important</div>
<div class="opacity important">opacity: .2 !important</div>
```

Note the code above will create objects automatically in `jQuery.cssHooks`, e.g. the lookup `$.cssHooks.color` will store `$.cssHooks.color = {}`. If you don't want that, use this other code.

```js
if ( // Check browser support
  window.Proxy
  && window.CSSStyleDeclaration
  && CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.setProperty
) {
  jQuery.cssHooks = new Proxy(jQuery.cssHooks, {
    get: function(hooks, name) {
      return new Proxy(hooks[name] || {}, {
        has: function(hook, setget) {
          return setget === 'set' || setget in hook;
        },
        set: function(hook, setget, value) {
          if(!hooks[name]) hooks[name] = hook;
          hook[setget] = value;
          return true;
        },
        get: function(hook, setget){
          if(setget !== 'set') return hook[setget];
          return function(elem, value, extra) {

            // Use the cssHook setter, if any
            if(hook.set) {
              value = hook.set(elem, value, extra);
              if(value === void 0) return; // No value
            }

            var style = elem.style;

            // Set the desired value without !important
            style[ name ] = value;

            // Get the computed value
            var computedValue = jQuery.css(elem, name);
            
            // Check if the computed value is the desired one
            if(computedValue === value) return; // OK

            // Set the desired value with !important
            style.setProperty(name, value, "important");

            // Check if the computed value has changed
            if(computedValue !== jQuery.css(elem, name)) return; // OK

            // Otherwise !important is not needed, so remove it
            elem.style.setProperty(name, value);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

// The elements in the collection that need !important will use it
$('.color').css('color', 'blue');

// The plugin is compatible with custom cssHooks
if(!$.cssHooks.opacity) $.cssHooks.opacity = {};
$.cssHooks.opacity.set = function(elem, value) { return value/4 + '' };
$('.opacity').css('opacity', .8);
```

```css
.color {
   color: red;
}
.color.important {
   color: red !important;
}
.opacity.important {
   opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="color">color: blue</div>
<div class="color important">color: blue !important</div>
<div class="opacity important">opacity: .2 !important</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't have to use too much complected code jquery provides you facilty to overwrite css rule

Simply use this

```
 $('#sendwrapper').children().css("cssText", "color: green !important;");
```

I am using `children()` because as I can see you have applied your css like this: `#sendwrapper *` So to consider `*` I am using `children()`.

And `cssText` simply overwrite your current CSS

And also the kind of module you are creating this is the best suited approach.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6L0p5gk9/

So no need to extend jQuery CSS function. The functionality you are looking for is already there

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of `jQuery.style` (search `style:` in the source code), find the line

```js
style[ name ] = value;
```

Just after that, add this code:

```js
// Get the computed value after setting the desired value without !important
var computedValue = jQuery.css(elem, name);

// Check if browser supports adding inline important styles
if(typeof style.setProperty == 'function') {

    // Set the desired value with !important
    style.setProperty(name, value, "important");

    // Check if the computed value is still the same
    if(computedValue === jQuery.css(elem, name)) {

        // Then !important is not needed, so remove it
        style.setProperty(name, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, It adds !important for all the properties. It should be set only when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin that first tries to add the desired rule, if nothing is changed, it adds the rule with `!important`. As far as I know, there is no way of testing, if the rule is set to be `!important`, but if the value doesn't change when trying to modify it with JS, you can assume that that's the case.

In short, it sets the !important declaration only if necessary:

```js
$.fn.extend({
    cssi:function(obj){
        var $target=this;
        $.each(obj,function(i,e){
            var initialVal=$target.css(i);
            $target.css(i,e);
            if($target.css(i)===initialVal && initialVal!==e){ //add !important only if the value didn't change and you're not trying to set it to the value it already had
                if(!isNaN(e)) e+="px";
                e+=" !important";
                $target.css(i,""); // clear any prior rules
                $target[0].style.cssText+=camelToDash(i)+":"+e;
            }         
        });
        return this;
    }
});

function camelToDash(str) {
    return str.replace(/\W+/g, '-')
    .replace(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2')
    .toLowerCase();
}




//Demo
$(function(){
    $("div").cssi({
        backgroundColor:"blue",
        height:100,
        width:100,
        color:"red"
    });
});
```

```css
div{ /*Just something to test it with*/
    height: 50px !important;
    width:50px;
    background-color:red !important;
    color:green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello world!</div>
```

Here's also a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vdctLh9/).

Answer (score -1):

// Clear the !important css

```
$('#elementToChange').css('background-color', '');

$('#elementToChange').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Or in a one-liner:

```
$('#elementToChange')
    .css('background-color', '')
    .css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Or you can add a class to it  by a predefined class in your css.